# Backbone View not rendering after fetch is successful

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug, backbone-views

I'm new to Backbone and trying to put together a small app and having problems getting a view to render client side.

Here is my client html in jade.

```
extends layout

block content
  .row
    #breadcrumbs.span12

  script#room-list-template(type="text/template")
    <td><a href="#"><%=name%></a></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-info">Join Room</button></td>


 script(src="/javascripts/dislocated_poker/index.js").
 script(src="/javascripts/dislocated_poker/nav.js").
 script(src="/javascripts/dislocated_poker/room.js").
 script(type="text/javascript").
 $(function(){
  DislocatedPoker.init();
})
```

This call my init function to fetch the data which is stashed away in MongoDb

```
DislocatedPoker = {
init : function() {
    var crumbView = new DislocatedPoker.BreadcrumbView({el : "#breadcrumbs"});
    crumbView.render();

    var rooms = new DislocatedPoker.Rooms();
    var roomListView = new DislocatedPoker.RoomListView({collection : rooms});
    rooms.fetch();
}
```

};

And here are my views and models.

```
DislocatedPoker.Room = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

DislocatedPoker.Rooms = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model : DislocatedPoker.Room,
  url : "/api/rooms"
});

DislocatedPoker.RoomView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName : "tr",
  render : function() {
    var template = $("#room-list-template").html();
    var compiled = _.template(template, this.model.toJSON());
    $(this.el).html(compiled);
    return this;
  }
 })

DislocatedPoker.RoomListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function() {
    this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    this.collection.bind("add", this.render, this);
  },
  tagName : "table",
  className : "table table-striped",
  render : function() {
    var els = [];
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
        var itemView = new DislocatedPoker.RoomView({model : item});
        els.push(itemView.render().el);
    })
    //return this;
    $(this.el).html(els);
    $("#room-list").html(this.el);

  }
```

})

I see JSON being returned from the fetch() method and the collection is iterated, but the result never ends up as client html. If I view the source of the HTML I see the following where the template should render.

```
<script id="room-list-template" type="text/template"><td><a href="#"><%=name%></a></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-info">Join Room</button></td>
```

I feel like I am missing something pretty obvious but can't seem to pinpoint the issue.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to replace bind with on ?

Comment: @Evgeniy, `bind === on`. Or stated another way, `bind` is an alias for `on`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following won't work:

```
$(this.el).html(els);
```

jQuery's `html` function takes a string, you're providing an array. Try with:

```
$(this.el).html(els.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
this.collection.bind("fetched", this.render, this);
```